# Ado.net SqlConnection Open method

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, sqlconnection

I am learning ADO.NET But it very hard for me... I dont understand why have got this compiler error:
"Declaration expected" for the connection.Open() .

I write this code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Basics

    Dim connection As SqlConnection = DataConnection.GetConnectToSql

    ' Here the error: "Declaration expected"
    connection.Open()


End Class

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class DataConnection

    ' SQL Server Connection
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = DataConnection.GetConnectToSql

    ' SQL Server Connection with connectionString method
    Public Shared Function GetConnectToSql() As SqlConnection
        Dim connectionString As String =
            "Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Payables;" &
            "Integrated Security=True"
        Return New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to execute functionality outside a method or property.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Basics
    Private connection As SqlConnection = DataConnection.GetConnectToSql

    Public Sub Open()
        connection.Open()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DataConnection
    ' SQL Server Connection
    Private connection As SqlConnection = GetConnectToSql()

    ' SQL Server Connection with connectionString method
    Public Shared Function GetConnectToSql() As SqlConnection
        Dim connectionString As String = _
            "Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Payables;" & _
            "Integrated Security=True"
        Return New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    End Function
End Class
```